# Get array from data-attribute

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a textarea with a given attribute, inside the data-attribute i insert an text.

```
<textarea id="txt-number" data-textset="{height: '600', content: 'test'}">
```

```js
$('textarea[data-textset]').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var data = $(this).attr("data-textset");
  console.log(data);
});
```

I use foreach because in some pages there are more than one textarea with the same data-attribute

I need to convert the text on data-attribute in array object.
Thank You

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, or what the problem is, because the data attribute holds an object not an array, and you don't seem to be inserting a date in to anything, let alone that object/array. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He is not using `.data`, just reading content of attribute via `data-textset`

Comment: @Justinas still doesnt answer how we get an array from the data?!

Comment: That's right, `data()` will solve part of the problem, but it's not clear exactly what he's trying to do, hence my comment for more clarification as the OP seems a little confused about objects/arrays and how they are used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 
  
  let allobject = $('textarea[data-textset]').map(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var data = $(this).data("textset");
     console.log(" Height = %s content =    %s",data.height,data.content);
    return data;
  });
  
  console.log(allobject);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
<textarea id="txt-number" data-textset='{"height": "600","content":"test"}'></textarea>

<textarea id="txt-number1" data-textset='{"height": "604","content":"test one"}'></textarea>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine? This does not even have explanation!

Comment: @Justinas  in my answer i have used var data = $(this).data("textset"); to get json value not   var dataAsAttr = $(this).attr('data-textset');
  var asJson = JSON.parse(dataAsAttr); and my code is self explanatory as you can run code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Put it as JSON and to later read it safe via `.data` API

```js
$('textarea[data-textset]').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var data = $(this).data("textset");
  var dataAsAttr = $(this).attr('data-textset');
  var asJson = JSON.parse(dataAsAttr);
  console.log(data, dataAsAttr, asJson);
  console.log(typeof data, typeof dataAsAttr, typeof asJson);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt-number" data-textset='{"height": "600"}'></textarea>
```

Comment: `$('textarea[data-textset]')` ...is this a right way to select an element?

Comment: Tested both with .data and with .attr but always returns in the form of a string and never as an array

Comment: @MarkZhiu I don't know how and where you tested. What output you see in my answer in console log second line? `object string` or `string string`?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian You can, but I think there is better ways to select elements

Comment: @Justinas I see string string both here and in my modified file

Comment: @MarkZhiu What browser are you using? IE6?

Comment: @MarkZhiu Check updated answer, I added `JSON.parse()` example too

Comment: @Justinas I used Firefox Quantum 67.0.4 and Chrome 75.0.3770.100 If i used Json.parse return this erro SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @MarkZhiu So it means you have wrong data passed, that's the problem...